# How do I extract data from the URLs?

Tags: python, web-scraping, data-science

I have a xlsx file where a lot of URLs are stored along with their serial ids. Each of these URLs redirects to a webpage where there is article written. My question is how do I scan all the URLs using python and store the title and the texts of the article in a new text file with the URL serial id as its file name?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using webscraping.

As you said, you have a xlsx containing tuples `(ids, url)`.

You could start by loading this into python with :

```py
import pandas as pd

urls = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

Then to read the content of each URL you can use one of the most famous Web scraping library in python : `BeautifulSoup`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# get the raw HTML from the request
content = requests.get(url).content

# build the soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

# get the title
title_tag = soup.find("title") # shows <title>ActualTitle</title>

title = soup.find("title").string # show ActualTitle


# You can get the whole text contained in the page 
text_content = soup.get_text()
```